# FirebaseUI with Firestore using React and a firebase.js file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Hello and thanks in advance for any help someone may be able to provide.  I followed a few tutorials and successfully created a firestore database that connects to my web app and allows me to interact with my database.  I am trying to add a sign-in screen to the application and have been trying to use FirebaseUI to simply incorporate a google sign-in.  I followed bezKoder's tutorial that had me create my web app using a firebase.js file that looks like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import "firebase/compat/firestore";



let config = {
   apiKey: "XXXX",
   authDomain: "XXXX",
   databaseURL: "XXXX",
   projectId: "XXXX",
   storageBucket: "XXXX",
   messagingSenderId: "XXXX",
   appId: "XXXX",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);


export default firebase.firestore();
```

The trouble I keep running into is that most of the additional resources I find simply put all of this code in the App.js file and I must be missing something when I go to add an additional component to my app. I followed an example that had me add this to my app.js

```
  state = { isSignedIn: false }
    uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: "popup",
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccess: () => false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ isSignedIn: !!user })
      console.log("user", user)
    })
  }
```

Hopefully someone can help explain where I am going wrong or point me in the direction of a tutorial using React, Firestore and FirebaseUI. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you help me understand the problem a bit more? Are you having problems with the authentication process, firebaseui, or how to structure your files? The problem description wasn't clear to me

> "The trouble I keep running into is that most of the additional resources I find simply put all of this code in the App.js file and I must be missing something when I go to add an additional component to my app."

Comment: First of all, thanks for trying to help, it may be more of a file structure problem because of the error messages I am getting.  I am trying to follow a two separate tutorials, one that I was able to successfully create a firebase CRUD web app and another that simply implements the FirebaseUI in an empty project.  I couldn't find any tutorial that creates a firebase database web app and uses the FirebaseUI.

Comment: For a reference, the two tutorials I have been following which both work independently are as follows:   https://www.bezkoder.com/react-firestore-crud/  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zq0TuNqV0Ew&t=865s

Comment: If you're looking for FirebaseUI web (and auth) tutorials, these should be right up your street. It's provided by the Firebase community and has a lot of resources that can help you if you poke around: [1] https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-web/ [2] https://firebaseopensource.com/platform/web | If neither of these help - feel free to update your issue with the error you mentioned and we'll try again.

Comment: Hello @Kerron,  Thank you for you help and I was able to get the FirebaseUI working in a project by following the links you sent me!  I have one more question about the file structure because I was able to get FirebaseUI working by including the code the tutorial in my App.js file however I would like to understand why some people do that work in a firebase.js file and is it better one way over another?

Comment: You're welcome. I think you're fine with doing it in your App.js file. I've not seen firebase.js used as a de facto way of writing firebase applications, so it might have just been specific to that tutorial. Good luck.